# console.log("hello world")が表示されない

Tags: javascript

#### エディター

visual studio 2017
windows10
空のhtmlで作成

#### 確認したこと

以下のhtmlをデバックした結果helloと表示されません。chromeの「設定」でjavascriptが許可されていることは確認。user agent style sheetでscript{display:none;}となっていましたが、ここから先どうすればいいのかわかりません。教えていただけないでしょうか？

javascriptを練習したいだけなのにできません。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log("hello word")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: はやとちりでした。解決方法を記載しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

#### 解決方法

ブラウザに直接文字が表示されるわけではない。
chromeのデベロッパーツール→consoleで確認するようです。

Answer (score 0):

console.log("hello word")
でデベロッパーツール→consoleで確認が面倒なら
alert("hello word")でもいいかもしれません。
この場合デベロッパーツールを表示させなくても、画面にポップアップが表示されます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。色々調べていたら、visualstudio codeというエディターがあるのがわかりました。vs code+node.jsというものがあればjavascriptは動きますという、知らない人がもしここ見たら参考にしてほしいです。